# Linking Table to Itself and Getting Relational ID

Tags: sql

I want to get accounts that have same id as other accounts and then ultimately figure out which account it s related to (see table below for example).

Table Structure

```
Account ID | flag | id2

123 | Y | 1

456 | N | 1

789 | N | 1

888 | Y | 2

999 | N | 2
```

Results I want:

```
Account ID | id2 | src_account_id

456 | 1 | 123

789 | 1 | 123

999 | 2 | 888
```

Here's the query that I have

```
Select account_id, id2, src_account_id
FROM table1
WHERE id2 IN (Select id2 FROM table1 WHERE flag = 'Y')
```

But I'm stuck with how to get src_account_id. I'm fairly sure it involves doing an inner join the table to itself, but I'm still not sure how to get the src_account_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. use a subquery to get `flag = 'Y'` result set. then self-join

```
SELECT  t1.AccountID,t1.id2,t2.AccountID
FROM T t1 inner join (
  SELECT id2,AccountID
  FROM T
  WHERE flag = 'Y' 
 ) t2 on t1.id2 = t2.id2
 WHERE t1.flag = 'N'
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7518b/7)

**[Results]**:

```
| AccountID | id2 | AccountID |
|-----------|-----|-----------|
|       456 |   1 |       123 |
|       789 |   1 |       123 |
|       999 |   2 |       888 |
```

Comment: Yup this works perfectly and gives the same results as query below. Good to know that I can do inner join as a subquery as well.

Answer (score 0):

Self join the table on `id2` and `flag`.

```
SELECT t1."Account ID",
       t1.id2,
       t2."Account ID" src_account_id
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN elbat t2
                       ON t2.id2 = t1.id2
                          AND t1.flag = 'N'
                          AND t2.flag = 'Y';
```

Comment: Works perfectly and exactly what I'm looking for - thanks a lot!